# Videos in image gallery of E commerce app

Tags: e-commerce, carousel, image-slider

Do you think users find videos more relevant than images in product image gallery of an ecommerce app and videos should be the first thing users should be seeing on landing on the product page of any product rather than a product image?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my opinion.

I learned few important things while using videos for ecommerce website specially fashion centric website like Myntra.com / amazon.in .

1. Videos are becoming very important aspect which results live feeling for the product.
2. Since, use of videos requires good internet data bandwidth for better visibility, one can use GIFs appropriately for same purpose.
3. For same reason as Point 2, videos should not be the thumbnail for the product. However, you can/must use light GIFs when user hovers over the product. This can applied to any e-commerce website. Same applied to product landing page. First thing should be image and next should be video in carousal.
4. Use of img tag inside video is a good option in case of issues in loading videos.

Thanks.